# Quicksilver not indexing Chrome bookmarks

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, quicksilver

When I first installed Quicksilver, I simply installed the Chrome plugin and everything worked beautifully. I could type in "face" and it would suggest "Facebook" from my bookmarks, type "red" and it returned "reddit", etc.
I just installed an update, and now the Chrome bookmarks no longer are shown in Quicksilver. I've tried restarting, clearing caches, even completely reinstalling the application itself. But nothing works.
[I have the proper plugins installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHsft.png), but they don't work. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.
First, close Chrome. Then, delete Bookmarks and Bookmarks.bak.
Open Chrome back up, and it will redownload your bookmarks. Restart Quicksilver and you're good!